# What does the tamper button on my STM3220G-EVAL board do?

Tags: stm32, cortex-m3, button

Reading through the reference manual of the [STM3220G-EVAL development board](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/USER_MANUAL/DM00022972.pdf) (an ARM Cortex-M3 dev/eval board) I see that it has a "tamper button", also weirdly referred to as an "anti-tamper button".

What is this tamper/anti-tamper button?

Comment: Too little information actually contained in the question.

Comment: Olin means he shouldn't be required to read a 66 page document. Tell us here what it says.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: A quick search for "tamper" reveals few results in the PDF.

Comment: @Random: Not our job to do a search to dig up information just to make sense of your question.  It's your job to provide the necessary information directly in your question.  Links can supply useful *background* information, but first order information belongs in your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a quick view into the datasheet, the "anti-tempering" is advertised as a feature of the microcontroller. The chip has hardware support for anti-tempering measures and the button is on the dev board for you to test and evaluate these features. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#STM32_F2:

> Static RAM consists of 64 / 96 / 128 KB general purpose, 4 KB battery-backed, 80 bytes battery-backed **with tamper-detection erase**.

You could use this feature to prevent sensitive data from being read from the device by opening the case and hijacking the battery-backed memory.

Answer (score 4):

I've used anti-tamper buttons in the past in home alarm systems. It's mainly a mechanical thing. The button is pressed (or released) when someone tampers with the device, i.e. opens the enclosure. You can attach any kind of action to it, from erasing certain sensitive data to calling security.

I don't see any use for this in an open development board, though.

Comment: Are there any "tamper buttons" that are used only for this kind of operation, like with really high reliability, or any button with matching mechanical properties (height, width etc.) will do?

Comment: Also the manual refers to a "tamper detection button", so it's probably related to it.

Comment: @abdullah - The ones we used were ordinary tactile switches with a high stem, with a spring attached that touched the housing. I don't know how they mounted the thing without the button being released.

Comment: @m.Alin - They also take tampering with the power supply into account, and deactivating the system doesn't disable the tamper button. (That would be too easy)

Comment: @stevenvh Of course. "I don't know how they mounted the thing without the button being released"  I thought you meant how the installers mounted them, not some burglars..

Comment: I see a use for that button if the whole dev board is to be fit inside a box for which we want to detect tampering.

Comment: @m.Alin lol. I don't know why but `...not some burglars..` sounds so funny :)

Comment: The use for the button on the dev board is so you can test whether your software reacts correctly to the button being pressed/released.